# Converting web.config to nginx config?

Tags: .htaccess, iis, nginx, webserver

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction to converting this IIS web.config code to nginx config? everything on google is about how to convert .htaccess to nginx config and nothing about web.config?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
  </system.web>



  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="2300" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>

  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="403" />
      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="File" path="403.php" />
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="File" path="404.php" />
    </httpErrors>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rule 1">
          <match url="^habbo-imaging/badge/([^/]+)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/habbo-imaging/badge.php?badge={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rule 2">
          <match url="^habbo-imaging/avatar/([^/]+)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="habbo-imaging/avatarimage.php?figure={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rule 3">
          <match url="^habbo-imaging/avatarimage/([^/]+)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="habbo-imaging/avatarimage.php?username={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rule 4">
          <match url="^habbo-imaging/head/([^/]+)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="habbo-imaging/head.php?figure={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rule 5">
          <match url="^gamedata/habbopages/chat/commands" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="gamedata/habbopages/chat/commands.txt" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rule 6">
          <match url="^gamedata/habbopages/chat/options" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="gamedata/habbopages/chat/options.txt" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rule 7">
          <match url="^gamedata/supersecret" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="gamedata/supersecret.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rule 8">
          <match url="^gamedata/external_variables" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="gamedata/external_variables.txt" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rule 9">
          <match url="^gamedata/external_flash_texts" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="gamedata/external_flash_texts.txt" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rule 10">
          <match url="^gamedata/override/external_flash_override_texts" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="gamedata/override/external_flash_override_texts.php" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rule 11">
          <match url="^gamedata/override/external_override_variables" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="gamedata/override/external_override_variables.txt" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rule 12">
          <match url="^gamedata/figuredata" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="gamedata/figuredata.xml" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rule 13">
          <match url="^gamedata/productdata" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="gamedata/productdata.txt" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rule 14">
          <match url="^gamedata/furnidata_xml" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="gamedata/furnidata.xml" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rule 15">
          <match url="^gamedata/habbopages/forums" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="gamedata/habbopages/forums.txt" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="API - Default">
          <match url="^api/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php?request={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule> 

        <rule name="API - Rooms">
          <match url="^api/room/([0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php?request=room&amp;room_id={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule> 

        <rule name="API - Groups">
          <match url="^api/group/([0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php?request=group&amp;group_id={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="API - Users">
          <match url="^api/user/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php?request=user&amp;search_type={R:1}&amp;value={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>     

        <rule name="API - Random Users with limit">
          <match url="^api/users/([0-9]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php?request=users&amp;amount={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule> 

        <rule name="HabboPages - Dynamic">
          <match url="^gamedata/habbopages/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="gamedata/habbopages/{R:1}.txt" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you find solution for this?

Comment: can you find solution for this?